# Reading a function from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem that when I click on `.test` it does not execute the `do_alert();` function and gives me a error:

> do_alert(); is not defined.

What's the problem? the main function `helpers` is already read when the page is loaded why can' get this function from `logout_users` function?

```js
var setup_system = (function($) {
  "use strict";

  return {
    init: function() {
      this.logout_users();
      this.helpers();
    },
    logout_users: function() {
      $(document).on('click', '.test', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        do_alert();
      });
    },
    helpers: function() {
      function do_alert() {
        alert();
      }
    }
  };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  setup_system.init();
});
```

NOTE: I try to re-read the helpers function by adding `this.helpers()` inside `logout_users` function but nothing change.

Comment: It's because you've defined `do_alert()` within the scope of the `helpers` function. You'll need to move that function to within scope of the object you return.

Comment: @M.Gara I add a note that I try this but like Pointy say that will not help.

Comment: Anything defined inside of helpers is a black box....maybe you wanted helpers to be an object of methods, not a function?

Comment: Add this line to `helpers`: `return { do_alert: do_alert }` and then use what m. gara proposed :D

Comment: @John I added it as an answer for you below with a full example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you've defined `do_alert()` within the scope of the `helpers` function.

To fix this you will need to move that function to within scope of the object you return. You could either put it at root level of the object (which would work fine, but could get messy if you have a lot of 'helper' functions) or you could nest it within your `helpers` property if you define that as another object. Personally, I'd use the latter to have some semblance of organisation. Try this:

```js
var setup_system = (function($) {
  "use strict";

  return {
    init: function() {
      this.logout_users();
    },
    logout_users: function() {
      var _obj = this;
      $(document).on('click', '.test', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        _obj.helpers.do_alert();
      });
    },
    helpers: {
      do_alert: function() {
        alert('foo');
      }
    }
  };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(function() {
  setup_system.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Click me</div>
```

Note that I cached the reference to the object as `_obj` outside of the `click` handler, as within that block `this` will refer to the clicked `.test` element.

Comment: @John no problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Do_alert function exist only in helpers method, so you can't access to it.

You need to declare your function directly in the logout_user method or outside, try this :

```
 var setup_system = (function ($) {
 "use strict";

 return {

     init: function () {
        this.logout_users();
        this.helpers();
     },

    logout_users: function() {

            function do_alert(){
            alert();
        }

        $(document).on('click', '.test', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            do_alert();
        });
    },

    helpers: function () {

        function do_alert(){
            alert();
        }
       }

   };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    setup_system.init();
});
```

Comment: So you are duplicating `do_alert` now? I think the point of the question is how to use helper function, function defined within `helpers` subobject. Not defining it inside `logout_users` this is not good at all.

Comment: @dfsq yes this is the point of the question. but thank you Leo R :)

Answer (score 0):

When `helpers` is invoked by the `init`function, all that is happening is that `do_alert` is being declared. But function declarations are hoisted to the top of their lexical scope. The lexical scope of `do_alert` is the scope defined by the `helpers` function. Therefore, `do_alert` is not accessible outside of `helpers` function.

A couple things you could do. The first one that comes to mind is: you could have the `helpers` method define a method called `do_alert` on the object being returned rather than merely declaring a function, like so:

```
   helpers: function() {
    this.doAlert = function() {
        alert();
    }
}
```

When your `doAlert()` is invoked by the event handler passed to jQuery, it will not work with the above solution. Instead you will need to make sure you call that `doAlert` on the returned object in that event handler. This is how you can do that:

```
 logout_users: function() {
    var self = this;
  $(document).on('click', '.test', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    self.doAlert();
  });
```